# RSelenium: how to use clickElement() to press a button that downloads file?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

I'm using Docker to get rsDriver running with RSelenium. Trying to navigate to [this url](https://2020results.asqnc.com/report.php?sid=1&did=1) and press the "Export to Excel" button which downloads a file to my computer's "download" folder. All seems to be running fine (no errors) but the file that should be downloading does not actually show up anywhere that I can find on my computer.

```
# A.C.E. Academy Webpage:
url <- "https://2020results.asqnc.com/report.php?sid=1&did=1"

#open Docker Desktop and start standalone_chrome
rD <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome", port = 4444L)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
remDr$navigate(url)
button <- remDr$findElement(using = "css selector", "button.btn.btn-success.ml-2")
button$clickElement()
```

Any clue what is happening? (Apologies if I missed anything as it's my first time asking a question - happy to post any additional needed info!)

Answer (score 0):

Using simple `xpath` we would be able to download the excel file,

```
remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", '//*[@id="printable"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/button[2]')$clickElement()
```

Your code too was able to download the excel file.

Comment: Thank you!! I realized my code actually works but it is rselenium/rsDriver() that is not executing correctly on my machine. It's never actually pulling up a browser (I assumed it was in the background but clickElement() doesn't produce any output)